# SQL Statement in CTE returns Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I´m pretty new to SQL and try to build my first CTE. This is the syntax:

```
    WITH myCTE AS
    (
        SELECT
            ProductID,
            MAX(Quantity) As MaxQuant
        FROM
            OrderDetails
        GROUP BY
            ProductID
        HAVING
            MaxQuant > 100
    )
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM MyCTE

    WHERE
        ProductID > 50
```

I tried that on the tutorial DB of w3schools.com if that is helpful. Is there any way to get a more helpful error than this?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'myCTE AS (SELECT ProductID, MAX(Quantity) As MaxQuant FROM OrderDetails GROUP ' at line 1
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_truncate

Comment: You're missing `FROM myCTE` in the outer query. Right now you have an empty `FROM` clause.

Comment: Also, you're running your query against MySQL, but you're using MSSQL CTE syntax. Simpler expressions will work in both MySQL and MSSQL, but you need to decide which one you're using.

Comment: thank you, adding the MyCTE statement did not solve it. Whats the difference? I guess the class in teaching in MSSQL and I try to solve my problem in MySQL.

Comment: MySQL only added support for CTE very recently. It looks W3Schools.com is running a very old version of MySQL that does not support CTEs. Instead you should use a locally installed version of MSSQL Server or use a site like SQLFiddle.com which lets you choose MSSQL Server specifically.

Comment: Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL. If ypu're being taught SQL Server, you need tio use SQL Server to write your queries. Very few queries are transferable between different RDBMS. Both Express and Developer versions of SQL Server are free to use; the latter for non-production environements only.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably `myCTE` versus `MyCTE` -- the first is how the CTE is defined and the second is how it is referenced.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41fa854e2268d62246d58f00519fcac3) is a db<>fiddle that shows it working with the names matching and not working with the case difference.  I note that in MariaDB (which is based on MySQL), this is not an issue.

Case sensitivity for table names, table aliases, and -- presumably -- CTEs is a bit tricky in MySQL. As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are not case-sensitive in Windows, but are case-sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Based on the [language describing CTEs,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) it is quite possible that they are stored in some temporary location of some sort:

> A common table expression (CTE) is a named temporary result set that exists within the scope of a single statement and that can be referred to later within that statement, possibly multiple times.

And due to using the underlying operating system, they might sometimes be case sensitive.

Note:  I'm pretty sure this is the case for CTEs.  Later the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) points out that table aliases ARE sometimes case-sensitive:

> By default, table aliases are case-sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or macOS. The following statement would not work on Unix, because it refers to the alias both as a and as A:
>
> mysql> SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name AS a
>              WHERE a.col_name = 1 OR A.col_name = 2;